# How do I get the index of an object in an ArrayList using only a property of the object?

Tags: java, object, indexing, arraylist

This is the ArrayList class, I am trying to get the index of the Account object by using only an Account Number. My Account Object consists of `((object)Customer, (double) Balance)` and my Customer Object consists of `((object) Name, (String) actNum, (object) Address)`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Database {

    //Instance Veriables
    private ArrayList<Account> list;  
    private Account account;
    private int index;
    private Boolean found;


    public Database()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Account>();
    }

    public void addAccount(Account a)
    {
        list.add(a);
    }

    public void deleteAccount(int i)
    {
        list.remove(i);
    }

    public void searchAccount(String actNum)
    {

        this.found = list.contains(actNum);
        this.index = list.indexOf(actNum);
        this.account = list.get(0);
    }

    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }

    public Account getAccount()
    {
        return account;
    }

    public Boolean isInList()
    {
        return found;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private int indexForAccountWithNum(String searchActNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (list.get(i).getCustomer().getAccountNum() == searchActNum)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Or in Java 8

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(i -> list.get(i).getCustomer().getAccountNum() == searchActNum)
    .findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: The thing is is that the accountNum isnt even in the Account class, it's in another sub-class called Customer. So it's like to classes deep and it keeps getting errors

Comment: I've added a getCustomer call. If you are getting errors your'll need to post the errors and any details of code triggering them.